# Marked For Death - everyone or just me?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

The demon hunter skill [Marked For Death](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/marked-for-death) has this description:

> Marks an enemy. The marked enemy will take 12% additional damage for the next 30 seconds.

Does this damage increase apply for other players as well or just the character that creates the mark?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everyone. This makes this skill very party-friendly.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was hoping as much. I like classes that have a bit of support flavour, even little things like this.