# Does "Marked for Death" stack?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

I saw the question [**Marked For Death - everyone or just me?**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67365/marked-for-death-everyone-or-just-me) and was thinking. If there is a party with 2+ Demon-hunters does this skill stack?

EDIT: Would they stack if they had different runes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do not stack as you will only ever see one buff of that type on the target.

Drew data from this question and links. [Do damage over time effects stack?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66936/do-damage-over-time-effects-stack)

Since it is a debuff on the target you will only see one Marked for Death on the target, a new cast or other cast will simply reset the timer. If there is similiar type buff then it would be a different debuff on the target and should stack.

Edit:
To answer the additional edited question, if we refer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69186/in-a-party-with-more-than-one-monk-how-do-mantras-work-together) then one can assume that they do stack because of the different runes. However, this is a debuff casted on a target, not a buff for the party. So I believe the answer is still they will not stack, but whoever cast the most recent one will have that effect. I don't know another demon hunter to test with at the moment, but I will update once I do.

Comment: You said "you will only ever see one buff of that type on the target", is there any skill that create a similar buff and for consequence don't stack with MfD? or by that you meant only for MfD?

Comment: Edited for more clarity :)

Comment: can you add to your answer another explanation about it. I did an edit into my question, take a look if you can.

Comment: Do you mean, "Would they stack if they had different runes?" The way you have it worded is a little confusing.