# How do you use "Marked For Death"? What's the best way?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

I'm a level 60 demon hunter who's just reached Inferno. I usually use Elemental Arrow w/ Nether Tentacles or Impale w/Chemical Burn as my main damage dealer and Hungering Arrow w/whatever rune to build hatred. I use a mix of Smoke Screen/Caltrops/Vault/Evasive Fire plus increased movement speed gear to kite around.

This seems like a pretty common sort of build, but I frequently see others using Marked For Death. I cannot seem to wrap my head around why. Would someone please describe a strong way to use it?

It seems like kiting and using the Steady Aim passive would automatically be better - especially on higher difficulties where you have to kite or be very mobile just to survive.

I'm not crapping on Marked For Death. I'm really curious about how other people use it.

Comment: On the higher difficulties, kiting far enough away to get the steady aim bonus is often very difficult. The speed some of these mobs have...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When playing single player one would probably gain more from the available passive skills. However, as pointed out in this [post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67365/marked-for-death-everyone-or-just-me), Marked for Death not only works for you, but all your teammates also benefit from its damage buff.

So, as Joshua pointed out, it can be used to ensure a certain amount of damage when you are unable to get away from the mobs or, when in group, have everyone get the buff.

Answer (score 2):

Marked for Death runed with Valley of Death is fantastic for chokepoints DPS increase when you're running with a melee tank. They can really benefit from the 12% increase in damage in a group setting.

Occasionally I also like Marked for Death runed with Mortal Enemy to get some additional hatred generation for particular boss fights, but I usually save those for hell farm runs when I'm allowed more leeway in picking up a situational skill without losing my neph stacks.

Answer (score 0):

I like use marker for death with the grim reaper ( or something like that is called)  its excelent for mass group do a multishot with that  crit everywhere  but in higher dificulty  I agree on the opinions above